# recurrent Service - time out issue

Tags: c#, rest, service, http-status-code-500

We have a web service that has been in prodcution for 6 months. 
For the last 2 months we have been getting intermittent failure. 
We are running a test bot that hits the service every 15 mins to make sure it works fine. The input parameters for the request is the same for every request from the test bot.
3 to 4 times a day we face the 500 error from the service.

The service that we hit calls another service which times outwith the following error message
The operation has timed out    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

What i dont understand is why the issue occured only recently and not from day one. Since nothing changed recently.

Also what should i do to re mediate the problem ??
Should I look at the timeout property ? or is there any thing else i could do ??

I am a database developer and i do have only a high level knowledge on services. Kindly help with this

Thanks in advance.
nk

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the IIS recycles the process of the service. Try configuring the recycling of the process to a fixed hour.

Comment: Thanks .. This is hosted in PCF. Pivotal cloud foundary. Is it the same recycle process there ?